# Regex precede newline \n with two spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string containing line feeds (`\n`).

I want to have all `\n`s preceded by two spaces.

```
var str = "First line\nSecondd Line \nThirdLine \\n";
str = str.replace(/\n/g, '  \\n')
```

The above works but adds more spaces each time I save it.

How can I leave it alone if already preceded by two spaces?

Comment: Use `/ *\n/g` instead?

Comment: Replace also existing `'  \n'`s with a `'  \n'`, not just `'\n'`s.

Comment: This is still confusing to me what is escaped, and what is not? what about `\\n` can you give us an expected output?

Comment: Accepted answer [doesn't work, proof](http://jsfiddle.net/L12n7wjn/3/), use my solution instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265580/regex-precede-newline-n-with-two-spaces/28265667#28265667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple regex is all you need:

```
/ {0,2}\n/g
```

Basically, it works on the premise that previously "replaced" strings will already have two spaces preceding each line feed, so it captures and replaces those as well.

```
var str = "First line\nSeconnd Line \nThirdLine \\n";
str = str.replace(/ {0,2}\n/g, '  \n');

// str === "First line  \nSeconnd Line  \nThirdLine \\n"
```

See what it captures [here](http://regexr.com/3ab2m), and see what it replaces [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L12n7wjn/).

**EDIT**

Sorry, my previous assumption had been that you wanted line feeds to be replaced by two spaces, then another line feed.

I didn't notice that you wanted the line feed escaped.

However, that's easy enough to do:

```
replace(/ {0,2}\n/g, '  \\n');
```

Just escape the backslash, see the newer version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L12n7wjn/1/).

Comment: If there are already 2 spaces this will add 2 more spaces, so at the end you will have 4 spaces.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE No, you are wrong. Have you even tried it?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE You haven't even tried your own answer.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L12n7wjn/3/ - your's doesn't work. I've tested mine multiple times, across different browsers and interpreters.

Answer (score 1):

Replace when there no spaces before the line break:

```
var str = "First line\nSecondd Line \nThirdLine \\n";
str = str.replace(/(\S)\s{0,2}\n/g, '$1  \\n')
```

Comment: That would leave line breaks with only a single preceding space alone.

Comment: My answer is much more elegant, yours doesn't even work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/L12n7wjn/3/